# In real analysis, is constant function measurable??

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions, outer-measure, measurable-sets

From my text book, it says that for a constant function $f(x)=c,x\in E, c\in\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty,+\infty\} $  is measurable.

The prove is saying that if $a>c$ then $\forall x\in E\rightarrow f(x)=c<a$, so $f^{-1}((a,+\infty])=\varnothing$, and $\varnothing$ is definitely an element of borel set in $E$.

On the contrary, it can be prove that $f^{-1}((a,+\infty])=E$.

Combining the above 2, we can say that it is measurable function.

However, this prove based on a condition that $E$ is the full set of its topology.

So if $E\subset X$ and $<X,T>$ is an topology, then $\varnothing, X$ has to be an open set, but $E$ does not have to be.

Thus $E$ can be out side of borel set of $X$, which actually make $f(x)=c$ not measurable??

Thus I would like to ask if I'm right and if yes, then why the text book commit the fact that constant function is measurable??

Comment: Properties of functions like being measurable, continuous, open, closed, etc., which depend on properties of the subsets of its domain or codomain, always assume that it's the (co)domain itself that carries the relevant structure, not some superset.

Comment: I believe this is just about measurability it does not talk about topology at all.  and function needs to be defined on all set so E is the whole space?

Comment: So it should be a base assumption that $E$ should have complete definition of its borel set and outer measure??

Comment: If $f(x)=c$ for $x\in E$ and $f(x)$ is something else for $x\notin E$ then $f$ is not a "constant" function! If $f$ is constant then $f(x)=c$ for _all_ $x$, the set $E$ doesn't come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people say $f : X \to Y$, by definition of this notation, $\text{dom}(f) = X$.  With that being said, the definition of a measurable function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ has nothing to do with the topology on $X$ (you do not need any topology of $X$). All you need is a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$. $f$ is measurable if for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}((a, \infty)) \in \mathcal{A}.$

What **is** true is that if $X$ does happen to have a topology, one natural $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel. But you can totally have others.

The book is correct. No matter what $\sigma$-algebra you have on $X$, a constant function will be measurable.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with topology. Suppose $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1)$, $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2)$ are measurable spaces. Pick any $c \in \Omega_2$ and consider the constant function $f: \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2, x \mapsto c$. Then for any $A \subset \Omega_2$
$$ f^{-1}(A) = \emptyset \quad\text{if c $\not\in A$} $$
and
$$ f^{-1}(A) = \Omega_1 \quad\text{if c $\in A$}. $$
But $\emptyset$ and $\Omega_1$ must be in $\mathcal{F}_1$ by the definition of $\sigma$-algebras. Thus, $f^{-1}(\mathcal{F_2}) \subset \mathcal{F}_1$ and $f$ is measurable.

Comment: I understand the prove, topology is used to define open set, so to define borel set. Measurable function mapping borel set to borel set....... However, my question is what if the domain of $f$ is a non-measurable subset of $\Omega_1$

Comment: If you consider a function from a space without assigned $\sigma$-algebra into a measurable space it makes no sense to talk about measurability of the function because it is not defined.

Comment: look borel set is the sigma algebra of openset by definition......... But my question focuse on the domian of function

Answer (score 1):

For any $q\in \mathbb Q$ we have either $\{f\leqslant q\} = \emptyset$ or $\{f\leqslant q\} = \mathrm{dom} (f)$ so $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot lol~~~ I know the prove but what if $\dom(f)\subset X$ while $X$ is well defined set with measure, and $\dom(f)$ is non-measurable set of $X$ ??

Comment: Roughly speaking, measurability is equivalent to having all information about the function. If the function is constant, you already know all there is to know about it.

Comment: @Shore By definition, the notation $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ means that $\text{dom} (f) = X$.

Comment: @Ovi My guess is he means he defines a new constant map on some subset of $X$ that is not measurable w.r.t the given sigma algebra.

Comment: @AlvinLepik To me it seems like he's not worrying about the map restricted to a subset of $X$, but rather about $X$ being embedded into a measure space (well topological space, since he seems to think that the $\sigma$-algebras we work with always have to be Borel)$Y$ and $X$ not being a measurable set (or a borel set) of $Y$. The answer to this is that $f$ *isn't* a function from $Y \to \mathbb{R}$, so when we check measurability, we don't care about $Y$. We only care about $\text{dom}(f) = X$ and it's own topology/$\sigma$-algebra.